# How to link to particular content type nodes via custom code

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a content type called 'xyz'. Under that taxonomy select list that contain a,b,c.
I am displaying taxonomy terms and I am able to display terms. I need to give link to content type nodes.here is my code. present it has linked to taxonomy/terms.

```
<li class='level".$level."'>".$bullet."<a href=\"$base_url/?q=taxonomy/term/".$value->tid."/pid/".$pid."\"> $value->name </a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view. Add a filter for content type. Then give that page url.

Comment: How to make in custom code? as in above link..any variables shd i change in the above?

Comment: what is your question. You dont want to do it with views?

Comment: I want to do through custom module ..that's y.....

Comment: In your SQL query, you need to specify the content type: $query->condition('n.type', 'xyz'). Also, you should use the l() function instead of outputting link tags and the theme_item_list() function to output lists.